# Python Pandas: How to delete row with certain value of 'Object' datatype?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe name `train_data`.

This is the datatype of each column.
[image]

The columns `workclass`, `occupation`, and `native-country` are of "Object" datatype and some of the rows contain values of "?".
[image]
In this example, you can see row index 5 has some values with "?".

I want to delete all rows with any cell that has any "?".

I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
train_data = train_data[~(train_data.values == '?').any(1)]
train_data
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

use `.loc` for index slicing.

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3,'?'], 
             'B' : [2,4,5,'?',9],
             'C' : [0,'?',2,3,4]})

print(df1)

   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
1  1  4  ?
2  2  5  2
3  3  ?  3
4  ?  9  4
```

---

```
print(df1.loc[~df1.eq('?').any(1)])

   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
2  2  5  2
```

---

if you only want to check `object` columns use

#### `pd.select_dtypes`

```
df1.select_dtypes('object').eq('?').any(1)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

### Edit.

One method for handling leading or trailing white spaces.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3,'?'], 
             'B' : [2,4,5,' ?',9],
             'C' : [0,'? ',2,3,4]})

df1.eq('?').any(1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

df1.replace('(\s+\?)|(\?\s+)',r'?',regex=True).eq('?').any(1)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

#### `str.strip()` with a `lambda`

```
str_cols = df1.select_dtypes('object').columns
df1[str_cols] = df1[str_cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.strip())

df1.eq('?').any(1)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out my issue. I noticed in the file that I work with, there is an extra space in front of the `?`. I have to use ` ?` instead.

Comment: @hongkongbboy you could use a lambda and apply a `str.strip()` you could also use `DataFrame.replace` gimme a mo